# VIsual Basic Applications If Statement that generates new userformbased on option box selection

Tags: vba

I'm new to VB and I'm programming an information control system for a chemical company. The program opens new windows(userforms) based how data is selected. I'm currently writing an if statement that goes through 3 option boxes. When a particular option box is selected I want to generate a specific userform which will contain a list combo box. The code for the if statement is posted below.

```
Private Sub UserForm1_Click()

 OptionButton1.Value = False
 OptionButton2.Value = False
 OptionButton3.Value = False

 If OptionButton1.Value = True Then
    UserForm3.Show     
 End If

 If OptionButton2.Value = True Then
    UserForm4.Show     
 End If

 If OptionButton3.Value = True Then
     UserForm5.Show     
 End If




Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
 Value.Show 

 -- Im aware that Value.Show is incorrect. I'm also sure that the reason the command button wont work is because the value from the options isn't being passed to the radio button, I think.

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want to open the forms as soon as an option is clicked, or when a button is clicked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the forms to open when the OptionButton is clicked then you are looking for this event:

```
Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    frmOption1.Show
End Sub
```

If you want the form to open after they have selected the option of which form and then pressed a "Submit" button or something of that sort then you want this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    If UserForm1.OptionButton1 Then
       frm1.Show ' assuming the name of the form is frm1
    ElseIf UserForm1.OptionButton2 Then
       frm2.Show ' assuming the name of the form is frm2
    ElseIf UserForm1.OptionButton3 Then
       frm3.Show ' assuming the name of the form is frm3
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If statement was above the radio button as a part of the Private Sub CommandButton1. I moved it to below the code for my confirm button and It works perfectly. Thanks for the help. Now on to setting up a DOA and get these combo boxes going =). Ill post all continuing work and work rlated issues to this thread, hopefully it will speed up the learning process for the other newbies out there. Thanks again. Mark

Comment: Hi guys

Ive created my Userforms and I have most of them populating the data to the cells quite nicely, however the combo boxes are a pain. I want to be able to save data that is entered into the combo box to a list which updates anytime a new reason is entered. The code I have so far is posted below.

Private Sub ComboBoxUL_Change()

Dim findblank As Integer
Do Until Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(findblank, 1).Value = vbNullString
findblank = findblank = 1

Loop
Sheets(Sheet2").Cells(findblank, 1).Value = ""

Comment: Post it in another question please.

Comment: Ive done that now sorry I wasnt aware it it didnt format code in the comments. Its its own question now =)